# Flex how to set Global Storage Settings to unlimited programatically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.7

Does anyone know how to set Global Storage Settings to unlimited programatically?
Thanks

Comment: For flash player security reasons this may not be allowed

Comment: Seems as though I've answered your question. Would you mind marking it as the correct one (unless of course it did not answer your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The GLOBAL settings must be configured by the user (It's a permission issue).

However, best practice would be to ask the user for permission to increase how much storage is allowed by your Flash app. This is achieved using:

```
SharedObject.flush(minDiskSpaceBytes:int = 0)
//Where the argument is how much space you anticipate ever needing
```

[Check out the Adobe reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush%28%29)

Lucky for you, **that request works on a domain level, so all Flash files hosted on that domain will also receive permission**. In a sense, that IS the global setting.